# Trigger azure pipeline based on multiple file changes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to trigger an Azure DevOps Build pipeline based on two files being changed simultaneously on my `master` repository, with the following trigger:

```yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - '**/*task.json'
    - '**/vss-extension.json'
```

My folder structure for this repository is something like this:

```
repository:

|--run-stryker
   --vss-extension.json
   --other files here ...
  |--task
     --task.json
     --other files here ...
```

Yet changes to these files at the same time are not triggering my pipeline. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately using wildcards like this in CI triggers is not supported at this moment. You can use `*` only at the end of paths but this is working the same as without this.
Wildcards like this are working in file matching in tasks but not in path trigger. So you must use exact paths like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - 'run-stryker/task/task.json'
    - 'run-stryker/vss-extension.json'
```

or using only folder paths like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - 'run-stryker/*' # is the same as 'run-stryker/'
```

Documentation reference: [Wildcards in CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards)

Comment: Your solution with full path works just fine. Yet I can't understand why my initial solution doesn't work as I have this **/*.csproj and this **/*Tests.csproj working just fine for me on another pipeline.